# ForkPoolTask.join() ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrentmodification, forkjoinpool

I'm getting a very strange error here that I can't quite understand. As it stands I'm making a crawler program that uses ForkJoinTasks to scan for links on the page and then crawl those as well. However, when I use .join() to collect the tasks, I sometimes get ConcurrentModificationExceptions pointing to that line.

```
Spider[] newSpiders = crawlForURLs("a", "href").stream()
        .filter(url -> SpiderUtils.isLinkURLValid(url))
        .map(url -> new Spider(url).fork()).toArray(Spider[]::new);

for (Spider c : newSpiders) {
    Image[] crawledImages = c.join();
}
```

The line in question is c.join(). I tried surrounding it in a ReentrantLock just to see what would happen but it made no difference.

Full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/qCJte65Q

Lines of code are:
at com.eulerity.hackathon.imagefinder.Spider.compute (Spider.java:85) (`Image[] crawledImages = c.join();`)

at com.eulerity.hackathon.imagefinder.ImageFinder.doPost (ImageFinder.java:45) `images = SpiderUtils.commonPool.invoke(baseSpider);`

I honestly can't figure out why this is the case, but if you need to see another part of my code please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem, and the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Slaw I wish I could provide that example but I honestly don't know how to reproduce the error, it only happens sometimes and I haven't found a pattern yet. I will update the original question with the full stack trace.

Comment: Hmm. The stack trace indicates the exception is being thrown from a stream pipeline. The only stream I see in your code is `crawForURLs("a", "href").stream()`. Make sure that you are not sharing the _source_ of the stream between multiple `ForkJoinTask` instances, at least not when that source can have read+write operations by multiple threads at the "same time" (without the proper synchronization).

Comment: @Slaw I'm not quite sure what you mean by sharing the source of the stream between multiple instances, I just pass the urls to the new instances and that's it for the results of that method. The code I provided is the only place where the stream is used.

Comment: Can you show your `ForkJoinTask` implementation?

Comment: @Slaw Here's Spider.java, which extends RecursiveTask: pastebin.com/8eDsVNDg and here's SpiderUtils.java: pastebin.com/5NpjY79T

Comment: From a cursory glance, I think I see the problem (improper synchronization). But I don't have time to properly look at it, or write a good answer, just yet. I'll try to get to give an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is in your `SpiderUtils` class. More specifically, this method:

> ```java
> public static boolean isLinkURLValid(URI url) {
>     return url.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(baseUrl.getHost()) &&
>             !containsURL(linksCrawled, url) &&
>             !containsURL(linksInProgress, url) &&
>             !url.getPath().contains(".");
> }
> ```

And this method:

> ```java
> public static boolean containsURL(ArrayList<URI> urls, URI left) {
>     return urls.stream().anyMatch(right -> urlsMatch(left, right));
> }
> ```

Both these methods are not `synchronized`, which means multiple threads can execute them at the same time. This is likely not a problem for the `containsURL(...)` method. Given what it does, it has no reason to be `synchronized` (neither it, nor the `urlsMatch(...)` method, rely on any external state). The problem is with how the `isLinkURLValid(...)` method passes both `linksCrawled` and `linksInProgress` to the `containsURL(...)` method.

These list variables are static, and thus the same instances are passed to the `isLinkURLValid(...)` method on different threads. This would be okay, if all you did was stream the elements of these lists (i.e., only *read* from the lists). However, elsewhere in your code you also *add elements* to these lists (i.e., you *write* to the lists). These writes are performed in `synchronized` methods, but that doesn't matter because you're reading the lists without synchronizing on the same object. So, your code is vulnerable to `ConcurrentModificationException`s (you cannot modify a non-concurrent collection while iterating over it).

*I believe* the solution would be to simply make the `isLinkURLValid(...)` method `synchronized`, but I'm not 100% positive as I haven't tested it.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly, thank you so so so much! I can't believe I didn't catch this one myself.